# How to make sure the speed in every android device is same for an android game?

Tags: android, scaling

I am working on a game and i am moving the background images by 4px. For this i had used a normal mdpi screen of 480X800. i have designed the game using this resolution.

To support different resolution i have used for Horizontal speed width/480. so, for 240X400 resolution the background image will move with 2px speed half of the 480X800. Same done for the the vertical speeds. But for some reason in 240X400 it moves faster then it is expected. I want to design it in such a way that no other player gets advantage due to its resolution.

Note: I am designing this using only processing & android. Screen-orientation - LANDSCAPE

Comment: there is something called DP. It is a pixel independent unit. Use that. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your scrolling speed in DP (e.g 10dp per second). Then you can read device DP using

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "density: " + metrics.densityDpi);
int pixelSpeed = (int) (densitySpeed * (metrics.densityDpi / 160));
```

Then your pixel speed will be different, but physical distance per scroll will be same.

More details in link from @harvey_slash

Comment: Okay i will try this out,but i have 1 doubt. Does the aspect ratio of the screen will have any effect on this? I mean for controlling the speed the above formula is sufficient right?

Comment: It should be sufficient. There is xdpi field in DisplayMetrics, but i think it will differ from densityDpi only in case of non rectangular pixels. You can try both of them...

Comment: I tried the above method. but it also not working.. in hdpi screen to cover distance between A & B is 9888 millisec and in ldpi it covers the same distance in 1192 millisec.

Comment: What was dpi speed? I thing it should be very small for proper work. densitySpeed=0.001f or something like it.

Comment: Well, i think i understood the issue even the pixel movement in every device is same but the FPS is different for different screen due to some device it moves faster and in some slower.